# CXF interceptors configuration for different endpoints

Tags: java, spring, cxf

Current CXF configuration:

```
<jaxrs:server id="rest" address="/path">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="myService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="restLogInterceptor" />
    </jaxrs:inInterceptors>
```

and spring rest:

```
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Path("path")
public interface Service {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    Response inquire(@PathParam("id") String id);

    @GET
    @Path("{id}\aaa")
    Response inquire(@PathParam("id") String id);

    @GET
    @Path("{id}\bbb")
    Response inquire(@PathParam("id") String id);

    @POST
    @Path("{id}")
    Response update(@PathParam("id") String id, Instruction instruction);
```

Any way how to

1. have different interceptors configuration for GET and POST endpoints with the same path?
2. have different interceptors configuration for endpoints with path variable? use mask like "/path/*/aaa" ?

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly understand what you want in first question. But if you want declare GET and POST methods with same path, its work. JAX-RS have @PathParam annotation which gets paramter from path in request. Using that with if statement you may create different logic.

Comment: I need different interceptors for different endpoints. Questions were corrected.

Comment: 1. Create interceptors(implement ContainerRequestFilter) and every input request(get data  from ContainerRequestContext) check that path match endpoint and http method type.
2. parse value in path with same solution

Comment: Thank you for response but I know about these ways and I want to avoid it.